# Error: Cannot find module 'extend' when running 'node skeleton build' in terminal

Tags: node.js, less

When Im compiling my .less file, I need to run `node skeleton build` in terminal, but instead of compiling, this error occur:

```
Building target: default
=============== ERROR ===============
{ Error: Cannot find module 'extend'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:594:15)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:520:25)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (/opt/lampp/htdocs/htlgi_london/lib/build/getSettings.js:3:14)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

Please show me how to solve this problem.

Comment: Why Downvote without explanation? that's why us beginners are scared of asking question here. Because instead of helping answering the problem, they just notice the wrong doing in asking a question.

Comment: Likely, the reason was because you didn't show us your code, so we can't diagnose the issue. Are you requiring `extend` anywhere? Have you installed it?